# Rollback on ItemProcessor and still call ItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch

I have an ItemProcessor that writes to the database and an ItemWriter that writes to a file. I want to be able to rollback in the ItemProcessor and still be able to pass by the ItemWriter.
To be more specific, my logic takes the object received from a FlatFileItemReader and uses it to do some maintenance to the database, if every thing goes good some properties are set in the object and if I face any database problem, I catch the exception and I set some other properties in the object. The processed object is later written to a file through a FlatFileItemWriter. I tried to extend the FlatFileItemWriter to throw an Exception after writing to trigger a rollback but doing so stops the things from going to the file.

Comment: `I have an ItemProcessor that writes to the database`: an item processor is not meant to write data. It feels like your issue is rather a job design issue than a problem in spring batch. What about splitting your job in two steps?

Comment: Exactly, it is a bad design but it is not mine and I am not allowed to make substantial changes to the Job designed by my superior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the **FlatFileItemWriter** is working with a **TransactionAwareBufferedWriter**, so there is no way to *rollback* the transaction and still write to the file on the disk as the **TransactionAwareBufferedWriter** will only flush to the disk if the transaction accomplishes without problems. So I did implement a pure *Writer* that implements the **ItemWriter** *interface* and I just throw an *Exception* just after writing to the file, flushing and closing the stream and it's working, it does rollback the transaction and in the same time it writes to the file on the disk.

I will not accept my answer for the moment to see if someone can come up with a better approach, maybe without loosing the benefits of having a **FlatFileItemWriter**.